# How to reference assemblies using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I would like to reference the System.Drawing.dll in a console app I am writing using Visual Studio Code on OSX. i.e. I want to use these using statements

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

to avoid this build error

```
Program.cs(56,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Bitmap' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I can't find a tutorial on this, I don't even know if the dll is available in .net core or mono or whatever visual-studio-code uses.

Comment: GDI and GDI+ are not available on OS X.

Comment: so is there anything similar I can use?

Comment: Add from menu : Project : Add Reference : Net Tab : System.Drawing

Comment: @Peter, [System.Drawing](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/drawing/), [Mono.Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/)

Comment: @jdweng there isn't a project menu in 'Visual Studio Code'

Comment: Please refer to kolim's solution posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-system-data-and-system-timers-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-co

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new .NET Core SDK restore command is **dotnet restore**

To add any asssembly reference in Visual Studio Code, please refer to my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399545/7634550).

Comment: I am not able to add System.Web.Script to use JavaScriptSerializer.

Answer (score 16):

In your .csproj file, add your dependency as a `PackageReference` in an `ItemGroup`, then run `dotnet restore` or `nuget restore`. Example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
  <PackageReference Include="Realm" Version="2.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit">
    <Version>2.3.1</Version>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) for a full explanation.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct since `project.json` isn't used in more recent versions of .NET Core (moved to `.csproj` project file format.)

Comment: Thanks @PerLundberg I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: How about referencing to a wsdl web service? Can I add the address to. Csproject and restore project?

Comment: @AProgrammer I'm not familiar with WSDL, but `nuget restore`/`dotnet restore` is only for nuget packages as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Mono offers a [WinForms pipeline implementation](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) that you can leverage, that includes support for `System.Drawing`.

Comment: the question isn't really about how to add System.Drawing specifically. It is asking how can I add a reference to ANY assembly using Visual Studio Code.