# Add existing DLLs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: openxml, visual-studio-code, openxml-sdk

My Mac has a virtual machine where Windows and Visual Studio is installed. However, running the virtual machine + Visual Studio is sometimes slow, so I am trying to use `Visual Studio Code` in Mac OS.

One thing I don't get is how to reference [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) in VS Code.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfSeqzMOXiQ&list=LL_WrYcTnXlz5Rjj9ZNwpWEA&index=1-) shows how to add Open XML SDK in Visual Studio. This idea is to download the code, and then compile them to generate 2 `.dll`, and browse to these 2 `.dll` to add:

[image]

Whereas, I don't see where to **add references** in VS Code.

Does anyone know this?

Additionally, is it possible to compile the downloaded folder (which contains `.sln`) directly in VS Code rather than Visual Studio?

PS: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324938/702977) modifies dependencies in `project.json`, and uses `dnu restore` to download the dependencies. But the problem is that `dnu restore` would not find my local Open XML SDK...

Answer (score 0):

You would add a dependency in your project.json file to DocumentFormat.OpenXml, then do a restore.

Comment: Is it possible to specify local path in `project.json`? Because `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` is local...

Comment: I you really need to use your own version of the DLL then you will have to compile it and then generate your own NuGet package.  You can then create a NuGet.config file that specifies a location on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for that... Additionally, is it possible to compile the downloaded folder (which contains `.sln`) directly in VS Code rather than Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to create a project.json file