Add local .dll file as reference in VSCode
An application I downloaded comes with a .dll file that can be referenced from a console application for automation purposes. However, I cannot connect it to my VSCode project.
I am currently using VSCode, C#, and .NET and I am trying to add that .dll as a reference to the project. I have tried to manually type it in .csproj and it is a local file on my computer, not in any external packages.

Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41519555/14513512

I don't have access to VS to follow this tutorial

Can you show us the csproj file with the change that you say does not work?
