# Can't reference dll assembly to the Visual Studio Code project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, .net-core

I am developing a console application in C# which requires some dll file to be referenced in Visual Studio Code(not Visual Studio!). There is no such option in menu I guess and I even tried Nuget package manager, but it does not worked for me. I cannot find any tutorial regarding this. Any experienced user?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/34324938/920557

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dotnet-add reference` CLI command which provides a convenient option to add project references to a project.

Example: Add a project reference:

```
dotnet add app/app.csproj reference lib/lib.csproj
```

For more information, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference).