# How to add refence to another project in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I couldn't find how to add reference to another project in VS Code in help documentation or in Internet.
The approach from [How to reference assemblies using Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888274/how-to-reference-assemblies-using-visual-studio-code) does work but looks really strange for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Just use `dotnet add reference [path to project.**csproj**]`.