# C# type does not exist in the namespace/name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have the line `using System.Deployment.Application;` at the beginning of my code. There is a red squiggly line under `Application` and mousing over it gives me the following information:

`The type or namespace name 'Application' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Deployment' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234)`

This of course gives me problems when I use `ApplicationDeployment` and it says `The name 'ApplicationDeployment' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)`

Why is Visual Studio telling me that `Application` is not a part of `System.Deployment`?

Comment: do you have a reference to an assembly that has that namespace in it?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't believe so... this is the only file in the project that references System.Deployment.Application

Comment: @DanielA.White I just trying running the line ```dotnet add package System.Deployment.dll``` and the terminal says the project does not support adding package references through the add package command

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio Code, open your.csproj file. In this file you can add an assembly reference to System.Deployment which should fix you issue.

Reference:

```
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment"/>
```

This will be added in the ItemGroup Section of the .csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Deployment"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Where can I find the Solution Explorer?

Comment: If it helps, I have VS Code verision 1.35.1

Comment: @katiedidkatie: Despite the confusing name, "Visual Studio" and "Visual Studio Code" are entirely different applications. I suspect you want to find a VS Code tag for your post.

Comment: read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888274/how-to-reference-assemblies-using-visual-studio-code

Comment: @katiedidkatie Like Jon mentioned, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two very different beasts. I was assuming that you were not using Visual Studio Code. This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000798/how-to-add-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-code/42399545